# LED array falsely triggering Arduino pin

Tags: switches, noise, arduino-uno

I have a strange issue where a limit switch is displaying as triggered the moment I turn on an LED driver with a relay. To complicate things further the issue doesn't occur 100% of the time.

The problem doesn't occur when the limit switches are sitting on the table, only when they're attached to the metal Z-axis.

I've since tried to insulate the mounting point with electrical tape but have had no luck.

So far I have tried.

- Adding a low-pass filter
- Adding optocouplers
- Separating LED and Arduino power supplies
- Limit switch trigger on high
- Limit switch trigger on low

Here is a circuit diagram.

Any suggestions on how to prevent these false readings would be extremely appreciated.

[image: Circuit diagram]

Comment: Look up answers for EMI solutions. Relay surge load noise

Comment: Does your software filter and debounce the input? Sample the input multiple times at around 100Hz. Determine how long the input must be active to consider it valid vs a transient. Then have your code enforce that.

Comment: Please provide a schematic. Without it, my best guesses are the same as always: poor layout, lack of flyback diode across relay coil, lack of decoupling.

Comment: Provide a real schematic, not a block diagram.